# NuGet jQuery Update - Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.ScriptManager.jQuery'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm trying to update jQuery using NuGet. I'm getting following message.

```
Successfully installed 'jQuery 1.9.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Updating 'jQuery 1.6.2' to 'jQuery 1.9.1' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.ScriptManager.jQuery' that is compatible with 'jQuery 1.9.1'.
```

I'm wondering how to solve this.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have a package called 'Microsoft.ScriptManager.jQuery' that you need to uninstall first.

Comment: Looking at the nuget packages it looks like Microsoft.ScriptManager.jQuery http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ScriptManager.jQuery/ has been superceded by AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery/ http://nuget.org/packages/AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery/ . Id try backing up your project, uninstalling (rather than updating) jQuery and then installing the new version of jQuery and the ASPNet version of scriptmanager.

Comment: Once I remove Microsoft.ScriptManager.jQuery** from project, it is working fine now. Please create it as an answer; I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the nuget packages it looks like Microsoft.ScriptManager.jQuery http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ScriptManager.jQuery/ has been superceded by AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery http://nuget.org/packages/AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery/ . Id try backing up your project, uninstalling (rather than updating) jQuery and then installing the new version of jQuery and the ASPNet version of scriptmanager.

Comment: Backing up? It's been a looong time since I've considered that. :-)

Comment: @MikeCole even with Source Control, nightly server backups and all that jazz I STILL cant get out of the habit of copying the files somewhere if Im about to do something potentially dangerous!  ;o)